# How to replace space from Python datetime object between date and time

Tags: python, python-datetime

I am looking to remove the space separating the date and the time from a python datetime object. I am using `strptime "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f"`, so I do not know why there is a space included to begin with.

Code:

```
import datetime
start_timestamp = "2022-11-23T10:08:00.000"
date_time_start = datetime.datetime.strptime(start_timestamp, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f")
print(date_time_start)
```

Output:
`2022-11-23 10:08:00`

Desired output:
`2022-11-23_10:08:00`

Comment: You asked why the space is printed. The `strptime` function returns a datetime, not a string. When you print it, a string representation of the datetime value is printed, and that, by default, contains a space, which is a completely sensible default.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`isoformat`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.isoformat) with custom separator:

```
>>> date_time_start.isoformat(sep="_")
'2022-11-23_10:08:00'
```